# .on event firing on load instead of click

Tags: jquery, dynamically-generated-co

Ok guys im new to jquery and have been making considerable progress but this one has me stumped. i have a event handler I'm binding to a dynamically loaded div to handle clicks hovers etc however when i try to bind a custom function it fires it on load instead of when clicked.

```
function AddUser(){
       alert('Hi');
       if ($section !== 'addUser'){
           $section = 'addUser';        
       $('.userPanel').empty();
       $('.userPanel').load('pages/addUser.html');
       }
       else{return;}
    }

    $(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser());
```

However if i define an event inside of the .on binding it works fine

```
        $(document).on("click", "a.addUser",function(){
        alert('Hi');
    });
```

I probably missed something elementary but this has had me frusterated all morning so any help would be appreciated.

Note: I realize that binding to document is generic and i should be binding to the one of my static parent divs it was just a change i made while testing.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Where is you code added ? Do you expect to function when you click on page ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser());
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser);
```

By adding the parenthesis to AddUser you're effectively calling it at that point in your code.

Comment: Thanks a million i figured it was going to be something elemental that helps out a bunch now i can move forward.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser);
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", function(){
   AddUser();
 });
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking +1

Comment: redundant anonymous function.. older versions of IE will start punishing you if you continue adding anon function like these..

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the parentheses from `AddUser()`

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser());
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser);
```

Because `AddUser()` is self-invoked and executed after page load.

OR

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", function(){
  AddUser();
});
```

because, `function() { AddUser(); }` is not self-invoked block and will execute everything within it when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

use function signature otherwise you will be invoking the function..
change it to

```
$(document).on("click", "a.addUser", AddUser);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3HW5/1/)**